# Is there a way to use a Java Writer object to write binary data?

Tags: java, outputstream, jira-plugin, writer

I want to use the writeSearchResults method of [this Jira plugin interface](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.7.1/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/searchrequestview/SearchRequestView.html).

The description of the interface says that it should be possible to generate PDF files but I am not sure how to do this correctly with just the Writer object that the method is passed. I would have expected to need an OutputStream object for this.

Even wrapping the Writer inside a [WriterOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/WriterOutputStream.html) still produces corrupted data due to extra encoding-related bytes.

Comment: `Writer`s in Java fundamentally write *string* data with an encoding, not raw bytes. That’s their sole reason of existence. I’ve no idea why Jira is using a `Writer` argument here, it makes no sense.

Comment: There is AbstractSearchRequestView on which to base your class, and maybe the sources of SearchRequestWordView might show how they did it. Piped I/O is feasible to a Reader with a liste of results you need to parse. Brrr. Pass a StringWriter while developing.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
    import java.io.*;
    
    public class WriteBinary{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
     
            if (args.length < 2) {
                System.out.println("Please provide input and output files");
                System.exit(0);
            }
     
            String inputFile = args[0];
            String outputFile = args[1];
     
            try (
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            ) {
                int byteRead = -1;
     
                while ((byteRead = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(byteRead);
                }
     
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

in this example we to binary data from a file and write it into an other.